# how to use javascript variable in php function?

Tags: php, jquery, function

do someone have any idea that, how can i use jquery variable ( CIF ) in my php function (myphpfunction();)? please look at the example below. i need to call **myphpfunction('1')** php function in #mydiv.

```
<script>
var CIV = parseInt($("#mydiv").attr("data-id"));
if(CIV < 4) { var CIF = CIV += 1; } else { var CIF = 1; }

$("#mydiv").html('<? myphpfunction("' + CIF +'"); ?>');

</script>
```

Comment: This is fundamentally impossible because PHP runs on the server and JavaScript runs in the browser, after the server has sent its data.

Comment: Php is server side, you can do this...

Comment: Please research what **JAVASCRIPT** and **PHP** are first, you seem to be confusing this.

Comment: But you cant echo javascript code using php.

Comment: ok.. thank you all. i should try another way to do it... (should i delete or edit this question?)

Comment: Don't you already have `<div id="mydiv" data-id="123">`? So, you could already generate the HTML that you need using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work. The jQuery is being executed on the client-side, after the page has been loaded in a browser, after all php processing has completed. By the time jQuery is being processed, php processing has finished.

I would suggest performing the functionality all in javascript/jQuery if possible. If not, consider using jQuery's [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the contents of a php script executed with that var.

E.g.:
test.php:

```
<?PHP 
    function myphpfunction($v){
    // Some processing here
    return 1;
    }
echo myphpfunction($_GET['v']); 
t?>
```

Your jQuery:

```
<script>
var CIV = parseInt($("#mydiv").attr("data-id"));
if(CIV < 4) { var CIF = CIV += 1; } else { var CIF = 1; }

$("#mydiv").load('test.php?v='+CIF);

</script>
```

Comment: good idea... but.. $("#mydiv").html(load('/test.php?v='+CIF)); doesn't work..

Comment: Sorry, load already sets the html to the contents of the loaded URL: $("#mydiv").load('test.php?v='+CIF); I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX would be your answer — by listening to a certain trigger, such as keyup, keypress, click or the likes, you can send JS variables to a PHP script, and fetch the output in a specific format (preferably JSON, or JSONP if you require cross-domain application).